# How to install openCV 2.4.9 for Visual C++ 2008 x86? (Unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, opencv

When I try to compile this code

```
// Project0.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get [38 errors and 4 warnings](http://codepad.org/XdkMSwf8)

I've specified all 3 folders with include files path:
[image]

[And lib files directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17771136/2136963)
[image]

As well as [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313819/2136963) .lib files:
[image]

The selected platform is Win32 and*.lib's are x86, so I think the problem differs from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474218/unresolved-external-symbol-error-when-importing-libraries-for-opencv2-3-in-visua), where x64 ones were used.

I can create a platform for solution and call it "x64", but cannot switch my project to it:

[image]

Comment: you can't link to vc10 libs using vs2008, you have to use those from the vc9 folder (if that exists)

Comment: then you will have to get cmake , and recompile from src. also, do yourself a favour, when trying out, *avoid* cli/managed c++. start with an *empty* project

Comment: update your vs. that's the most easy solution.

Comment: Thank you. But what's wrong with managed c++?

Comment: opencv is *stack* based (RAII, refcounted objects), cli is all about pointers and gc. does not play well together. you can't even imread() an image with a bloody String^ , so please avoid all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `berak` said, it's easier to get a Visual C++ 2010. To use opencv 2.4.9 with MVC++ 2008 one should recompile the library from sources